# Documentation on geting driving directions and calculating driving distance with Mapstraction

Tags: javascript, maps, mapstraction

I'm trying to build an easy to use map system for the applications we develop at work. I started using Google Maps but I have to abandon that because of the lack of SSL support. While Google Maps API Premier has SSL support, we can't afford the 10k a year fee. I'm considering using [Mapstraction](http://mapstraction.com/) so that in future, if I need to change providers it's much less of a hassle. However, what I'm primarily interested in, calculating the driving distance between two points, seems ti have no documentation for doing with Mapstration. Their website says that driving directions are available, but the API for this appears to be poorly documented. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep an eye on the mapstraction mailing list as this feature is being implemented in v2 soon.